# would n dimensional extreme point of Polytope hiding form all n-1 dimensional coordinate projection?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Given a Polytope $X \subset R^n$ and assume we have nonempty extreme point set $P(X)$.

We can do have $n$ different $n-1$ coordinate projection (namely hiding one coordinate). We use $h(X, i)$ indicates $i$th coordinate get hidden.

Would it be possible For $n \geq 3$, $\exists x \in P(X), h(x, i) \notin P(h(X, i)), \forall i \in {1\cdots n} $ ?

For a $n =2$ case is kind of trivial to prove, take $X$ as a pentagon, and there are 5 extreme points. and project it to both X and Y axis would result in two line segments which in total there can be maximum 4 distinct extreme points. So that there must be 1 extreme point missing.

I'm having a trouble prove it for $n =3$ case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the convex hull of $n+1$ points consisting of the standard basis vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ together with $v_t = (t, t, \ldots, t)$ for some $t \in (0, 1/n)$. Then the projection of $v_t$ is in the interior of any coordinate projection.

Comment: why is $v_t$ an interior of convex hull  of standard basis ?

Comment: all of its coordinate projections are, is the point.

Comment: sorry, I asked the wrong question. I think the counterexample in the request is to find a point on the boundary in $R^n$ space and no longer in $R^{n-1}$ space. the $v_t$ in the example is not on the boundary of the hull of standard basis though.

Comment: Ah, but $v_t$ was supposed to be one of the $n+1$ vertices of the convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I tried to clarify that a bit.

Comment: ah because all 0 is not included, I see what do you mean now, thanks!